# .eps extension vs. epstopdf

Tags: epstopdf

This MWE does not compile in TeX Live's `pdflatex`, despite a file `A.eps` and an subdirectory `gfx` in the current directory:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{gfx/}}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{repstopdf #1 --outfile=gfx/\OutputFile}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{A.eps}
%   \includegraphics{A}
\end{document}
```

The file `gfx/A-eps-converted-to.pdf` is correctly generated, but not found.

I am pretty sure that it did compile in MiKTeX, but I am unable to test this now.

(It does compile when I replace `A.eps` by `A`; or when I remove `gfx/` from `\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule` and add `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=gfx/}`.)

Why is TeX Live sensitive to having the extension there? Is this one of these many, tiny differences between MiKTeX and TeX Live? Is this considered a bug?

Comment: Can't speak to MiKTeX, but on MacTeX 2017, a MWE of `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx} \graphicspath{{gfx/}} \begin{document} \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a} \end{document}` with `a.eps` saved in the `gfx` folder works fine. I get a file `a-eps-converted-to.pdf` in the `gfx` folder, and the PDF gets included in my document.

Comment: Your example fails for me both with texlive and miktex and also without the extension. The reason is that you are overdoing with the `gfx`: epstopdf tries to put the converted pdf in `gfx/gfx/` (which can work if the folder exists) and pdflatex can't find it there. The example without the extension probably works for you because you have some A.pdf or A.png that pdflatex finds instead.

Comment: @MikeRenfro yours is the variant of the MWE which works for me, too. It does NOT compile when replacing `a` by `a.eps`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can confirm that both variants do not work when I replace `A` by `erklgjergergep`, and renaming the `eps` file accordingly (to prevent `pdflatex` from picking up some other `A.eps`). So maybe I had another file with that name somewhere. Still, I do not agree that `epstopdf` tries to put a file in `gfx/gfx/`; even if that folder exists, the file is created in `gfx/`. It's just not found, however; not even when I copy it there manually.

Comment: I didn't use `a.eps` as a parameter because it shouldn't be necessary. Using just `a` should make `pdflatex` should look for `a.pdf`, `a.png`, `a.jpg`, etc. And if it finds `a.eps` and no `a.pdf` (or if `a.pdf` is older than `a.eps`), it should (and in my case, did) convert `a.eps` into `a.pdf` automatically.